# How to Change Timezone of scrapydweb?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I just Install scrapydweb in my system and my problem is I can't change the Timezone.

The Default is UTC+00:00 and I want to change it to UTC+03:30.

How Can I do this?

I change the timezone of my Linux server to Asia/Tehran.
But unfortunately this problem still not solved.

Comment: according to [this](https://github.com/my8100/scrapydweb/issues/96#issuecomment-539269613)  it looks like you just need to restart the server once you have set the timezone

Comment: I restarted the server many times. and note that I create scrapydweb with docker.

Comment: I have no experience with scrabydweb, in fact this is the first time I have heard of it.  I see you have already opened an issue on github, that is likely your best bet for getting an answer. You might want to mention the docker part in your issue as well, and [edit] your question here with that information as well.

Comment: @Alexander Can you recommend an alternative to scrapydweb?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following code into Docker Compose and then start the build again.

```
environment:
  - TZ=Asia/Tehran
```